# What does "provisional proposals" mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> We published our consultation paper on 27 October 2010, setting out
>   our *provisional proposals* for comprehensive reform of the law on
>   unfitness to plead in England and Wales. We received over 50 responses
>   and, on 10 April 2013, we published an analysis of those responses.

I know that provisional could mean many meanings (temporary - conditional - limited , etc)

Could provisional mean *a stock* since the word *provide* has this meaning ? so the sentence speaks about a stock of proposals.

or could it mean *current* ?
a current proposal is better I think.

The problem is that I do not find any dictionary gives these meanings.

Edit: to think of provisional as temporary is somewhat difficult because I find it strange that an institution gives temporary proposals to reform the law (why the institution make all these efforts to make just a  temporary proposals?)... but yes sometimes it may do. 
The other thing is the word *provide* and its relation to *provisional* 
So in my mind I wondered if provisional could mean a stock, and came the idea that the institution might have given a stock of proposals.

Comment: The only meaning given in the first four dictionaries I consulted is the first  you suggest: "temporary, subject to future alteration". What about that meaning is puzzling?

Comment: @StoneyB - I made an edit to answer your question.

Comment: It's standard in the US, and apparently the UK: an agency publishes tentative proposals for a new law or regulation and invites public comment and suggestions for revision before moving ahead to a final version to be laid before legislators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjective "[provisional](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provisional)" is synonymous with "temporary" or "tentative" and it means:

> existing or accepted for the present time but **likely to be changed**.

If a proposal has not been completed and is likely to be changed after getting responses from various interested parties, you make a provisional proposal. And after all items are fixed, you make a "definite" or "final" proposal.

Comment: @GamalThomas My pleasure. This link could be helpful in understanding the etymology of the word "provision" http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=provision&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: the  etymology of the word "provision" did not say temporary but all goes to supply a food or providing beforehand,foresight, preparation, prevention. 
that makes me wonder.:)

Comment: @GamalThomas When you do something with care, precaution or foresight, preparation, it means you are not making a hasty conclusion. When you make a proposal with care or precaution, it means it could take more time to make it final. The meanings are related.

Comment: maybe yes, but I found this etymology for provisional (not provision). 
it seems they are two different words. yet maybe they are related as you said as well. 
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=provisional

Comment: @GamalThomas When you learn a word, it is better to find more examples on how it is used. There are millions of examples where provisional means temporary. Don't rely too much on a dictionary.